# The idea of weakly locally connected (connected im kleinen) points, and counterexamples.

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, locally-connected

I've recently had the chance to learn about the [weak local connectedness (connected im kleinen)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConnectedimKleinen.html)  property, of points in topological spaces.
Also, I've been trying to construct a space which has some specific point which is weakly locally connected but not locally connected.

This sort of construction seems a bit difficult, because for some point $x 
\in X$ (where $X$ is our space) to be weakly locally connected but not locally connected, there must be some open $x \in U \subseteq X$ such that if $N \subseteq U$ is a neighborhood of $x$ then $N$ is not open. Also, at least one such connected $N$ should exist for any arbitrary selection of $U$.

After some time I've found the [infinite broom space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BroomSpace.html) to provide this sort of example, but actually nothing else (other than constructions of pretty similiar patholgical subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Question:

- Are there any other known examples of weak local connectedness
  without local connectedness? (I've failed to find)
- What is the significance of this concept when studying connectedness of topological spaces? (the assumption that there is some significance, is because someone bothered to name it)

Comment: Sounds like the sort of technical condition needed to do things like classifying all connected covers of a space.

Comment: Looks like there are Julia sets that are im kleinen at a point. https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/The-Julia-Sets-of-Basic-Unicremer-Polynomials-of-A-BLOKH/58941498e2535c2cd30dc01ffed4c9b433960a38/abstract

Comment: The broom space is an example.  See the link in the link you gave for the definition of connected in the small.